# How to access a return value of a function that is being traced

Tags: r, debugging, trace

Is there any way of accessing return value of a function that is being traced by a function specified as exit param to trace? That sounds hard to understand, but I was not able to simplify the question without loosing the information. So here is a simple example.

We have a simple function

```
add10 <- function(a){
  a + 10
}
```

And some function that we want to be called when call to add10 exits.

```
trace.exit() <- function(){
...
}
```

Tracing is set up the following way.

```
trace(add10, exit=trace.exit)
```

And we do a call to add10

```
add10(5)
```

As I understand of right now, `trace.exit` will be called after `add10` finished executing. Is there any way to access return value of `add10` inside `trace.exit`?

I feel that there should be. But playing with `sys.frames` and looking through environments I was not able to get it.

The reason for doing so is a wish to capture all calls to some function and return values they give.

*UPD* Solution with wrapper or something similar is nice, but `trace` already implements a decorator pattern, so my question is about accessing return value from `trace`, not about solving the problem of decorators in R.

Comment: It is difficult to see where that return value is hiding. In C, the values some close to each other in [context.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/fba3c1b0ac71bb5a681b2c1437ce2a38dfa3bb61/src/main/context.c#L197). From what I can tell, the `jumpfun` is supposed to set the return value to `val` in the correct context, but it appears the `on.exit` function may run in a different context. I was hoping it might be available in `.Last.value` but that appears not to be the case. Perhaps it's the UI that updates that value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use a wrapper that explicitly assigns the return value to a local variable:

```
add10 <- function(a){
  a + 10
}

wrap <- function(f) { function(...) { ..ret <- f(...) } }

add10_wrap <- wrap(add10)

trace.exit <- function() {
  cat(sprintf("Return value: %s\n", sys.frame(-1)$..ret))
}

trace(add10_wrap, exit=trace.exit)

add10_wrap(5)
```

One downside is that the wrapper will always return invisible results -- that's why the above example only prints the formatted output.

Comment: Thanks, this is a perfectly valid solution, but not really scalable. Also I want `add10` to be callable by same name, not by wrapper name. And trace already gives a decorator solution. Now I am just wondering if it is possible to get access return value in that.